# Symfony2 - NotBlank constraint not working on EntityType

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, constraints

I have two `EntityType` fields in my form and both has `NotBlank` constraint assigned to them.

Now, I have this issue that `NotBlank` constraint is not working only on one field with `multiple => true` set on.

```
$builder
    ->add('preferredCountries', EntityType::class, array(
        'required' => false,
        'class' => 'IndexBundle:Country',
        'property' => 'name',
        'empty_value' => 'Choose',
        'multiple' => true,
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                ->where('c.name != :name')
                ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC')
                ->setParameter('name', 'Other');
        },
        'constraints' => array(
            new NotBlank(array(
                'message' => 'blank!!!',
            )),
        )
    ))
    ->add('internshipProgram', EntityType::class, array(
        'required' => false,
        'class' => 'IndexBundle:InternshipProgram',
        'property' => 'name',
        'empty_value' => 'Choose',
        'constraints' => array(
            new NotBlank(array(
                'message' => 'blank!!!',
            )),
        )
    ))
```

In this case when I submit empty values, field `internshipProgram` get an error, and `prefferedCountries` not.

Form display:

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-12">
    {{ form_label(current_internship_form.preferredCountries, 'Preferred countries', { 'label_attr': {'class': 'label-text'} }) }}
    {{ form_widget(current_internship_form.preferredCountries) }}
    <span class="error text-danger small">{{ form_errors(current_internship_form.preferredCountries) }}</span>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-xs-12">
    {{ form_label(current_internship_form.internshipProgram, 'What type of training agreement will you have?', { 'label_attr': {'class': 'label-text'} }) }}
    {{ form_widget(current_internship_form.internshipProgram, { 'id': 'internship_program', 'attr': {'class': 'form-control '}}) }}
    <span class="error text-danger small">{{ form_errors(current_internship_form.internshipProgram) }}</span>
</div>
```

Is there a mistake in my code or is it somehow related to multiple choice selection? Has anyone had similar issue and know how to solve it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't use `NotBlank` constraint on `EntityType` with `multiple` set to `true`. As the array will never be null. You should try using the `count` constraint like this:

```
$builder
    ->add('preferredCountries', EntityType::class, array(
        'required' => false,
        'class' => 'IndexBundle:Country',
        'property' => 'name',
        'empty_value' => 'Choose',
        'multiple' => true,
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                ->where('c.name != :name')
                ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC')
                ->setParameter('name', 'Other');
        },
        'constraints' => array(
               new Count(array(
                   'min' => 1,
                   'minMessage' => "Should not be blank"
               ))
            )
    ))
...
```

Comment: Also you can specify at Entity level, so all form using above entity will get validation,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41099599/symfony2-notblank-constraint-not-working-on-entitytype/57852890#57852890

Answer (score -1):

Also you can specify at Entity level,

```
    /**
     * @Count(min = 1, minMessage = "At least one branch must be selected")
     */
    protected $multiCheckBox;
```